# Why when I run Gedit can't I change the theme?

Tags: gedit, globalmenu

When I run Gedit as a regular user I don't get the menubar that lets me change preferences.

But when I run Gedit from the command line (`gksudo gedit`) then I get the menubar that allows me to use Edit->Preferences->Font & Colors, etc.

But when I just run `gedit` from the command line without the `gksudo` part, I don't get the menubar at all. How can I run Gedit as myself and get the menubar? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty Narwhal) was released, menubars are no longer located directly underneath the application's titlebar. They are located in the top panel which you can access by moving the mouse over. This is called the global menu.

Comment: Wow. Even after reading your answer I had trouble figuring it out. I wouldn't have discovered that for a long time. Got it!